# Best practice for using datetime in Pymongo query path?

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, pymongo

How can I use datetime object in case I need some complex path? For example I want to increment counter which is located in `jumps/datetime.date()/country code`:

```
database['data'].update_one(
                {'some_data' : 'asdasd'},
                {'$inc' : {'jumps.{}.{}'.format(datetime.now().date(), "US") : 1}},
            )
```

This code will work, but (as expected) there is a string instead of datetime object:

```
"jumps" : {
    "2017-04-14" : {
        "US" : 4
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you save your data, where some key is date object? Could you show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to store date object as a key in mongodb document.
Also, you shouldn't use value as key, because you can't use keys in queries or indexes. It would be better if you change structure of your document and simplify it.

Something like that:

```
"jumps" : {[
    {'date': ISODate('2017-04-14'), "US" : 4},
    {'date': ISODate('2017-04-14'), "RU" : 9}
]}
```

or you can create new collection `jumps` which will contain documents:

```
{'date': ISODate('2017-04-14'), "US" : 4}
{'date': ISODate('2017-04-14'), "RU" : 9}
```

or another structure

Look at this article https://derickrethans.nl/mongodb-arbitrary-key-names.html